# Value on props is undefined after change name but she is there

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to implement redux in my react native app.
Everything is ok, but when I change name of my array, application can't rendering the list.

In class App extend Component I have:

```
placeAddedHandler = placeName => {
    this.props.onAddPlace(placeName);
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <PlaceDetail
                selectedPlace={this.props.selectedPlace}
                onItemDeleted={this.placeDeletedHandler}
                onModalClosed={this.modalClosedHandler}
            />
            <PlaceInput
                onPlaceAdded={this.placeAddedHandler} />
            <PlaceList
                places={this.props.places}
                onItemSelected={this.placeSelectedHandler}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

in placesRed.js

```
const initialState = {
    places: [],
    selectedPlace: null
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PLACE:
            return {
                ...state,
                places: state.places.concat({
                    key: Math.random(),
                    name: action.placeName,
                    image: {
                        uri:
                            "https://www.randomImage.jpg"
                    }
                })
            };
```

now if I change places from initialState to placesList, app can't rendering.
In debugger we can see in Placelist.js:

```
const placeList = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.listContainer}
            data={props.places}
            renderItem={(info) => (
                <ListItem
                    placeName={info.item.name}
                    placeImage={info.item.image}
                    onItemPressed={() => props.onItemSelected(info.item.key)}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

data={props.places} -> here props have my value and places also, but with different name example: props.placesList I still have value in props but placesList is "undefined"

of course i change name place to placesList in everywhere in my app

What can be wrong ? How to fix it ? If u want more code from my app, tell me.

**after change:**

PlaceList.js

```
const placeList = props => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.listContainer}
            data={props.placesList}
            renderItem={(info) => (
                <ListItem
                    placeName={info.item.name}
                    placeImage={info.item.image}
                    onItemPressed={() => props.onItemSelected(info.item.key)}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

placesRed.js

```
const initialState = {
    placesList: [],
    selectedPlace: null
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PLACE:
            return {
                ...state,
                placesList: state.placesList.concat({
                    key: Math.random(),
                    name: action.placeName,
                    image: {
                        uri:
                            "https://www.randomImage.jpg"
                    }
                })
            };
```

App.js

```
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <PlaceDetail
                    selectedPlace={this.props.selectedPlace}
                    onItemDeleted={this.placeDeletedHandler}
                    onModalClosed={this.modalClosedHandler}
                />
                <PlaceInput
                    onPlaceAdded={this.placeAddedHandler} />
                <PlaceList
                    places={this.props.placesList}
                    onItemSelected={this.placeSelectedHandler}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**data={props.placesList}** -> this props have my value, but placesList is undefined

Comment: Can you update your code, after changing/making all the modifications? Thanks.

Comment: ok, done, check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **App.js**, you need to pass the prop to the `placesList` to your **PlacesList** component

```
<PlaceList
  places={this.props.placesList} // <== replace places with placesList
  onItemSelected={this.placeSelectedHandler}
/>
```

Comment: but why this work with "places={this.props.places}" ? its only different name

Comment: The prop name that you define in the Parent Component is reflected in the child, therefore you can use either of the case.